# While finding anti-derivatives, can I multiply a denominator with a square root by -1?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to find the anti-derivative of the function: $$ \frac {x + 3}{\sqrt{5-4x-x^2}} dx $$

To begin with, I multiplied the denominator to write the integral as: $$ - \int \frac {x+3}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4x - 5}} $$

I got this anti-derivative: $$ -\sqrt{x^2+4x-5}-\frac{1}{6}\log\left(\frac{\left|x-1\right|}{\left|x+1\right|}\right) $$
While the textbook answer is:

$$ -\sqrt{5-4x-x^2}+\arcsin\left(\frac{x+2}{3}\right) $$

I checked my entire process and the difference seem to arrive because I multiplied the denominator by - 1 at the beginning, although I also multiplied the whole integral by -1, which seems to work fine at other cases.

I tried to see if these two integrals are equivalent using desmos, but it throws up two very different graphs for the textbook answer and the answer I got. [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ttckeoiczr) is the graph, and the image for convenience (red is the textbook answer):

[image]

Comment: Multiplying the square root by $-1$ is *not* multiplying the radicand by $-1$.

Comment: $-\sqrt{a} \ne \sqrt{-a}$.  In real numbers: If $\sqrt{a}$ only exists if $a \ge 0$ in which case $\sqrt{a}\ge 0$ and $-\sqrt{a} \le 0$ and $-a \le 0$ so $\sqrt{-a}$ will not exist unless $a = 0$ (which it cant because it's in the denominator).  This is simply the wrong way to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying by $-1$ under the square root sign and overall is not correct.  Note that $\sqrt {-1} \neq -\sqrt 1$  Aside from branches in the square root you have multiplied the denominator by $\pm i$ and the overall expression by $-1$.

As you are working in the reals, the original problem tells you that $5-4x-x^2 \gt 0$ or $9-(x+2)^2 \gt 0$ so the range is restricted to $(-5,1)$.  You have negated that, so your integral is valid over $(-\infty,-5) \cup (1,\infty)$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: yes, I dropped the sign.  Fixed.  Thanks

Comment: The range is retricted to $(-5,1)$, isn't it?

Comment: @AlexSilva :yes I am having sign trouble

Comment: @RossMillikan -- Thank you, that was a silly error to make. But it was also insightful for me to know that the integral was valid everywhere the original integral wasn't! Thanks for pointing it out. It  Even with the graph, that fact escaped my eye.